# HTMX can trigger without attributes like hx-post-get-put...?

Tags: javascript, html, django, htmx

I have a form like below. if "Cancel Request" is clicked in the form, "delete__product" form element will be destroy. my problem here is that HTMX cannot work without (I hope not) a process like hx-post-get.... is there a solution for this?

```html
<form method="post" id="delete__product">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <p>Are you sure you want to delete ""?</p>
    <button href="javascript:void(1)" hx-trigger="click" hx-target="#delete__product">
    Cancel Request
    </button>
    <button hx-post="{% url 'catalog:DeleteProduct' product.pk %}" hx-target="#delete__product">
        Delete
    </button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The docs for `hx-trigger` say:

> hx-trigger can be used without an AJAX request, in which case it will only fire the htmx:trigger event

Rather than `hx-trigger="click"`, perhaps [hx-on:click="..."](https://htmx.org/attributes/hx-on/) and inline JS, using the built in [API](https://htmx.org/api/).

```html
<button href="javascript:void(1)" hx-on:click="htmx.remove(htmx.find('#delete__product'))" />
```

Despite the fact that it's not documented,  I think this shorter version will also work:

```html
<button href="javascript:void(1)" hx-on:click="htmx.remove('#delete__product')" />
```

Shortest:

```html
<button href="javascript:void(1)" onclick="htmx.remove('#delete__product')" />
```